# Android Emulator audio not working on a particular computer

Tags: android, android-studio, audio, android-emulator, emulation

Running the latest Android Studio emulator on a particular Windows 7 machine using arm images (x86 is problematic because would require re-compiling libraries). None of the emulator's built-in sounds will playback, and attempting to play a mp3 with MediaPlayer results in:

E/MediaPlayer: error (-19, 0)

but the app plays successfully on other machines. Interesting enough, running a Mac OSX image w/Android Studio on this same hardware also gives the same error. Next step will be perhaps to update the audio drivers... but is there any other advice? (please don't suggest changing to GenyMotion or ditching emulation, these are not options).

UPDATE 2/17/17: Noticed I get the following error messages as the emulator is trying to boot up:

```
 I/AudioPolicyManagerBase: loadAudioPolicyConfig() loaded /system/etc/audio_policy.conf
 E/AudioFlinger: int android::load_audio_interface(const char*, audio_hw_device_t**) couldn't open audio hw device in audio.primary (Function not implemented)
 I/AudioFlinger: loadHwModule() error -38 loading module primary 
 W/AudioPolicyManagerBase: could not open HW module primary
 E/AudioPolicyManagerBase: Not output found for attached devices 00000002
 E/AudioPolicyManagerBase: Failed to open primary output
 E/AudioPolicyManagerBase: getDeviceForStrategy() speaker device not found for STRATEGY_SONIFICATION
 E/AudioPolicyManagerBase: getDeviceForStrategy() speaker device not found for STRATEGY_SONIFICATION
 E/AudioPolicyService: couldn't init_check the audio policy (No such device)
```

I have made sure the Audio drivers were the latest from the motherboard manufacturer. Also, the Android Emulator does indeed show up as a volume slider on the Windows Audio mixer.